# get models submodels and their submodels laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Can anyone tell me how to get models submodels and their submodels in the controller using eloquent? I have Organization model, Car, CarPrice, ModelDetails and Car images, so far I managed to get all the data using

```
$cars = $organization->cars()->with('model_details')->with('car_price')->with('car_images')->get();
```

But I want also to get submodels of ModelDetails, Manufacturer for example, is there any nicer way to do it without looping through all cars? I've set relations properly in models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.` operator for nested relations as:

```
$cars = $organization->cars()
                     ->with('model_details.manufacturer')
                     ->with('car_price')
                     ->with('car_images')
                     ->get();
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) scroll down to `Nested Eager Loading`

Comment: sure, just when I reach reputation over 15, i cannot do it for now :)

Comment: You don't need 15 reputations to accept an answer. check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work